# Yii2 migrate dump SQL

Tags: sql, yii2, migration

Is possible to dump in a file the SQL of the executed migration(s)? (or before executing? like a dry-run)

I took a look into the sources and if I'm not wrong the current implementation doesn't handle it, but probably wouldn't be too complicate to add the option, or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy right now but still possible.

You would have to override `yii\db\Command::execute()` to return raw SQL instead of executing it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction, to me currently the complex task seems to be to find how/where to inject the overriding class. Right now have no time to try it, but hopefully I will soon, then I'll get back here to confirm

Comment: @Alex you can do it i.e. by using a classmap, override the class there right before the extraction. I'm doing the same thing in my [migration extension](https://github.com/bizley/yii2-migration/blob/master/src/Updater.php#L72).

Comment: Thanks, perhaps that's the way but my yii knowledge is still too limited, I've extended the migrate controller and in its init() placed the classMap to my MigrationSql but seems like isn't working (if I modify the migration extending  to my MigrationSql instead of Migration of course it works)

Comment: Actually got it working, ugly as easy, nothing fancy but a start, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute raw SQL inside Migrations, since `yii\db\Migration` class has an `execute($sql, $params = [])` method, like

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

/**
 * Handles the creation of table `{{%users}}`.
 */
class m220914_163215_create_users_table extends Migration
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function safeUp()
    {
        $this->execute("
            CREATE TABLE `users` (
                `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                `updated_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                `created_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
                UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
                UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5705 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
        ");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function safeDown()
    {
        $this->dropTable('{{%users}}');
    }
}
```

Then just run `php yii migrate` and your table must be created.

Comment: Thanks @victorf, I'm no longer using Yii but sometimes I still use migrations, it took me a while to understand what you mean, I knew you could use raw SQL, I never thought about using only those in migrations, very interesting.